# Combine "Water" and "Water Purification" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Is there any substantial and worthwhile difference?  It seems to me that all water items should be put together.

Answer (score 4):

All water purification items fall under water, but not all water items fall under water purification:

- How much water should I take per day on an average hike?
- How can I stop water from freezing?
- What do I need to look for in a good water bottle?

For that reason I think they should be kept separate.

Comment: My thought is that water purification is so small of a subset that it should all just go under "water".

Comment: @RussellSteen I think they should be separate too. We can check in a few months, and if there are a trivial number of water-purification tags, we can reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to see water remain distinct for a bit unless we can establish how we might want to tag water-sports or water-activities such as canoeing, lake boating, lake sailing, ocean boating and sailing.

Water purification (or more broadly - establishing a secure, sanitary, reliable water source) is one of the big three survival criteria that each of us faces when we leave civilization and head outdoors.

- water
- food
- shelter

I suppose a good tag wiki will help shape things once the site has moved past beta, but it seems a little early to equate water to water-purification to me (who has only recently arrived so may be unaware that this is already worked out somewhere but not yet in the tag wiki)